# Theorem style: All letter uppercase

Tags: environments

What do I have to do, the create a theorem environment, where the theorem name has a different style than the standard one?

I want the name to be all capital letters. Obviously `\newtheorem*{new
thm*}{\textsc{newtheorem}}`  doesn't work as it doesn't change anything - but `\textsc{Newtheorem}` is precisely how I want my theorem name to be displayed. Here's a MWE that hopefully makes that clear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem*{newthm*}{\textsc{Newtheorem}} 
%Change \textsc, so that indeed has all letters capital

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I want the "Newtheorem" to look like \textsc{Newtheorem}. 

But instead, it looks like:

\begin{newthm*} A Theorem
\end{newthm*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `\newtheorem*{newthm*}{NEWTHEOREM}` sufficient?

Comment: @egreg no, because 1) Then all letter have the same height, whereas something like `\noun{Newtheorem}` produces an "N" that is slightly higher then the other uppercase letters. 2) Everything is bold, but I want it just displayed normally.

Comment: `{\scshape Newtheorem}` is what results in "all capital letters" of different sizes.  but whether or not bold is applied is usually a function of how this is defined in the document class, and you haven't told us what document class you are using.  a compilable example would be really helpful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Unfortunately, \scshape doesn't change anything. I've reworked my question and added an MWE. (Interesting, \textsc{...} works in the body of the text, but not in this command ?)

Comment: Your MWE doesn't work, please correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration `\theoremstyle{theorem}` is wrong: it's `\usepackage{amsthm}`. Then this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{newthm*}{\normalfont\scshape Newtheorem}

\begin{document}

I want the "Newtheorem" to look like \textsc{Newtheorem}.

But instead, it looks like:

\begin{newthm*}
A Theorem
\end{newthm*}

\end{document}
```

[image]